# Building connection pool in a service and using them in other services

Tags: java, spring-boot, jdbc, microservices, c3p0

In a micro-service architecture built using Spring-Boot and Eureka Service discovery, I am building C3P0 connection pools for many applications in a separate single service.
But when I am trying to return the created connection pools to their individual applications as an object and use a connection from that object, it is not working.

For example -
When we directly create a DataSource using C3P0, we write -

```
ComboPooledDataSource dataSource = new ComboPooledDataSource();
dataSource.setDriverClass(...);
```

But when we want to the dataSource to use Connection Pool created in a different micro-service, is there any example/Github to get it ?

Comment: Are you going to pass database connection pool from one microservice to another via http? This will not work. Each microservice should have its own connection pool, this is how it works. You can pass some serializable data source configuration between microservices to make sure that all of them connect to same database using same user, but each microservice will have its own connection pool.

Comment: Thanks you very much! That's exactly what I was looking to confirm, Ivan.

What is the way out ?

Comment: There are 2 options: use monolithic application with one datasource or pass some configuration object between services. That object will contain driver name, database url, username, password and each service will create it's own datasource pool based on that config object

Comment: Thanks Again Ivan; My app structure is not monolithic, let me analyze the other option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not possible to pass populated connection pools between services, because they need to live (and load classes from) the address space of that Java application, and the physical connections also need to be from that Java application. You'll need to solve this differently.

What is possible is to pass a configured data source between service. That will essentially serialize or externalize the data source configuration, and build a new one with that same configuration. Be aware though that not all data source implementations support that.

That is something that has existed for years in Java, and how for example JNDI servers could be used to look up configuration data for a distributed application, or how JavaEE applications can share configuration data with Java client applications. That is a practice that - in my experience - is becoming less common in favor of using things like Spring Cloud Config, etc.

Comment: Thanks Mark. How is Spring Cloud Config coming in this context ? I mean does this config provide any other solution which is not traditional but solves this problem otherwise ? Helps me if you could elaborate this too.

Comment: @AnkurB.Roy Spring cloud config just provides the config and the consuming service will need to apply that itself, while JNDI can contain actual configured Java objects, which can be serialized between services, or some form of metadata-object. The difference is the amount of coupling and complexity. What you are trying is not possible, and would only lead to a poor variant of JNDI, while things liks Spring Cloud Config is simpler in that situation (in my opinion).

Answer (score 5):

A DB connection is essentially a TCP connection under the hood, which is uniquely identified by a pair of sockets in the participating hosts. Here a socket means the combination of a network address (IP) and a host address (port).

When a TCP connection is established all these details are stored on either end points in a data structure called TCB. Thus, you cannot just migrate a TCP connection from one host to another.

There are some research on TCP connection migration like [this one](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-snoeren-tcp-migrate-00). However, the main objective here is *not* performance (as in connection pool by saving the time of TCP 3-way handshake during connection establishment), but to allow the existing connections to continue and not break due to IP change on account of mobility or failover.

If you refer to the linked paper above, the core concept is to again do the 3-way handshaking to create a new connection with the new IP. The only difference is that during the handshaking some additional control data will be passed to update the TCB with the new host data such that the ongoing data transmissions can continue without being broken due to IP change.

Thus you cannot just transfer a DB connection from one host to another because the hosts have different IPs. The above paper I linked is in draft version. Even if it is implemented, it won't help your cause because as I said migration will again require the handshaking which is what you want to avoid in connection pooling.

If you somehow transfer the data source from one host to the other and then try to borrow a connection from it, the connection test that the datasource does before returning a connection will fail and this will continue untill all the connections are exhausted and then new connection for that specific host will be created. So, eventually you won't gain anything out of it.

Finally, the idea of hosting all connection pools in a single microservice (although inherently wrong due to the facts mentioned above) seem to go counter with the microservice based architecture. It would create a bottleneck and any issue with this microservice will bring down your entire infrastructure. In microservice architecture we want to localise the problems rather than spreading. Your individual microservices should be autonomous as much as possible and the patterns like bulkhead and circuit breaker go a long way to acheive this.

Comment: I understand. Thanks for in-depth explanation.